# Javascript : Just can not get a Loading GIF to display

Tags: javascript, sleep, show-hide

I am not very skilled in javascript, but I thought I was doing something quite simple.

I have an HTML file, which can be run just in a browser, because in use there will be no access to wifi or cellphone.  I am using javascript only to minimise resources needed.

It searches approx 6500 records and returns matches.  This works fine on android (1 to 2 secs), but iPad3 (Only IOS I have to test on), takes around 30 seconds, so I want to add a "Searching DIV" to show it is running.

I created what I thought was a simple test to try this out - sleep loop and a show/hide div for my searching message.

The Searching DIV is never seen and I do not understand, why the 
progress messages are not displayed at one second intervals, but all at once when sleep loop is completed.

I have obviously misunderstood some internal processes.

```
<style>
    #LoadingGIF { z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px ; margin-left: -100px;
    display: none; }

</style>
<title>tutSleep</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Sleep and Searching message test</h1>
    <div id="process">

    </div>
    <div id="LoadingGIF">
        Searching for your matches  
</div>
<!--    <img id="LoadingGIF" src="Loading.gif" />
--> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    showResults();

    function showResults() {
        var p = document.getElementById('process');
        p.innerHTML = "";
        var g = document.getElementById('LoadingGIF');
        g.style.display = "block";


        for (var x=1;x<6;x++) {
            sleep(1000);  //sleep fo 1 second
            p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + getDateTime() + "<br>";
        }
        g.style.display = "none";
    }

    // Delay for a number of milliseconds
    // This will be a big javascript text search of approximately 6,500 text strings of 100+ characters.
    // It performs well on Android and
    // this GIf not really needed but iPad 3 it can take up to 30 secs.
    // 

    function sleep(delay) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
    }


    function getDateTime() {

    var date = new Date();

    var hour = date.getHours();
    hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;

    var min  = date.getMinutes();
    min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

    var sec  = date.getSeconds();
    sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;

    var day  = date.getDate();
    day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;

    return year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "&#160;&#160;" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you thought about fixing the whole "takes about 30 seconds" situation?

Comment: It is a simple javascript array of  strings and I do a match on one or two words against each array entry.  As it works so well on Android (Galaxy S4 and newer Galaxies), I do not know of any method, to make it simpler.  The HTML file in total is 2mb.

Answer (score 0):

When you do sleep like this, that has many disadvantages.

It eats up all the resources it can and it blocks the javascript "thread", it will also cause an out of memory problem very fast.

Instead of using a while, make javascript really wait:

```
var lastCall = -1;
var timeToSleep;
var callback;
function sleep(delay, cb) {
    if (lastCall == -1) {
        lastCall = Date.now();
        timeToSleep = delay;
        callback = cb;
    }
    if (Date.now() - lastCall < timeToSleep) {
        requestAnimationFrame(sleep);
    } else {
        lastCall = -1;
        callback();
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
sleep(6000, function() {
    // 6 seconds later
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I will implement this when I get back home - travelling at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded. In this simple test, you are consuming that thread and therefore you will not see that GIF until your whole showResults() method is not completed.

With actual code (in which you would be making AJAX call), your above logic should work. Also having "position:fixed" is more suitable in such scenarios as that will keep showing progress gif at a fixed position even if you will play with scroll.

Updated:
You may place your data (JSON) in separate JS file and then may load that file using $.getJSON() function. Show your gif before calling this function and then hide it in success function.

Comment: Thanks for the fixed tip.  To keep it simple, because it is all offline, I have avoided libraries.  The data is contained within the HTML file as a javascript array.

Comment: If data is part of your html page, it means data + html are downloaded at client side together. And then processing happens. In this way, you may use setTimeout function to do your processing junks but that will not be good approach to handle it. Issue is with downloading, not with processing (I assume).